# Pandas Dataframe: From dictionary, generate a dataframe which contains the key multiple times depending on the values of the key

Tags: python, pandas

I'm extracting data from multiple PFDs files. I'm struggling now on how to structure in an Excel file the results. I came up with a dictionary with this format:

```
{'pdf_path_1': [extracted_text_a,extracted_text_b,extracted_text_c],
{'pdf_path_2': [extracted_text_a,extracted_text_b,extracted_text_c],
{'pdf_path_3': [extracted_text_a,extracted_text_b,extracted_text_c]}
```

Real example: https://gyazo.com/1fa8955abd00e8d6088dc35cedc03be9

I'm converting it to a dataframe, but it happen this:

https://gyazo.com/95c4f3654d4440de99bb45db8a17c068

My idea is show this in a dashboard, so I need to have the results in this format:

https://gyazo.com/3cccd58f71b23c0ba495eef9b0a96f01

The extracted text it's just a code with this format XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-000000

Also, do you think that this dictionary is properly implemented to this type of concerns?

```
a = {}

for doc_path in docs_path['file_path']:

    print(f'reading doc: {doc_path}')

    try: 
        with open(doc_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:

            text = extract_text(doc_path)
            related_docs = re.findall(r'\bCRL(?:-[A-Z]{3}){4}-(?:\d{6}|X{6})\b', text)
            a[doc_path] = list(set(related_docs))
        
    except:
        print('Error')
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way finally:

First, change the structure of the dictionary to this one:

```
a = [{'doc_path': 'pdf_path_1', 'doc_values': ['extracted_text_a', 'extracted_text_b']},
     {'doc_path': 'pdf_path_2', 'doc_values': ['extracted_text_a', 'extracted_text_b', 'pyko','pyko2']}]
```

So, the code would be:

```
textextracted = []

for doc_path in docs_path['file_path']:

    print(f'reading doc: {doc_path}')

    try: 
        with open(doc_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:

            text = extract_text(doc_path)
            related_docs = re.findall(r'\bCRL(?:-[A-Z]{1,6}){4}-(?:\d{1,10}|X{1,10})\b', text)
            textextracted.append({'file_path': doc_path, 'related_docs': list(set(related_docs))})

    except:
        print('Error')
    continue
```

Then, do a for loop under that list with dictionaries inside, and append them in a new list.

```
for element in textextracted:
    a.append(pd.DataFrame(element))
```

Then, concatenate the previous list:

```
textextracted = pd.concat(a)
```

Final results:

https://gyazo.com/47720ec924dc56a41e33f710c3ebfec3